# OleDB ' Unspecified error' VB

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am using oledb to get data from .txt file and i have encountered error.

```
Dim oleDB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\CompName\C$\Path;ExtendedProperties="Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed""
```

where CompName and Path are real values

I get Unspecified error in adapter fill

```
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(oleDb)
        Using command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
                adapter.Fill(s)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return s
End Function
```

anyone tried geting data across intranet from different computer using oledb?

Comment: You set the format as FIXED, did you have a SCHEMA.INI describing the structure (A.K.A. Schema) of your text files? http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/fixed-length-columns/

Comment: yes i have - but i'll check with default delimiter to be sure

Comment: Check also with a 'normal' sharename without the hidden share C$, it could be a permission problem.

Comment: OK you were right - I had schema.ini but in different folder :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the OleDb Text Driver with a text file formatted with fixed length columns you need to have a **SCHEMA.INI** file in the same folder where the text files are located.
The **SCHEMA.INI** allows to define various property for the text file like Format, Field Names, Widths and Types, character sets and some conversion rules.

From MSDN

> When the Text driver is used, the format of the text file is
>   determined by using a schema information file. **The schema information
>   file is always named Schema.ini and always kept in the same directory
>   as the text data source.** The schema information file provides the
>   IISAM with information about the general format of the file, the
>   column name and data type information, and several other data
>   characteristics. A Schema.ini file is always required for accessing
>   fixed-length data. You should use a Schema.ini file when your text
>   table contains DateTime, Currency, or Decimal data, or any time that
>   you want more control over the handling of the data in the table.

More details about the SCHEMA.INI file could be found [on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yeah i just forgot that i moved file without schema :) now everything wokrs like a charm Thanks!